# declaring var inside if statement c#

Tags: c#, variables

I have this var, but I want to change it's content depending on the statement, I can't get it working because when I use it, VS says it has not been declared, even if the statement is true...

```
if (DateTime.Today.Day > 28 && DateTime.Today.Day < 2)
{
    var days = GetDaysLikeMe(DateTime.Today).Take(50).Where(d => d.Date.Day > 28 && d.Date.Day < 2).Take(4);
}
else
{
    var days = GetDaysLikeMe(DateTime.Today).Take(50).Where(d => d.Date.Day < 28 && d.Date.Day > 2).Take(4);
}
```

EDIT:

I've tried to declare the variable outside the box... But can't get it working neither, the function I keep on var days is this

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDaysLikeMe(DateTime currentDate)
    {
        DateTime temp = currentDate;
        while (true)
        {
            temp = temp.AddDays(-7);
            yield return temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use it? Inside of the `if` or `else` block? Or outside?

Comment: Never declare variables inside an if statement, most compilers should stop you doing this. Declare the variable first, then change it depending on the statement.

Comment: How could `DateTime.Today.Day` be greater than 28 and less than 2 at same time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the scope of the if statement:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> days;

if (DateTime.Today.Day > 28 && DateTime.Today.Day < 2)
{
    days = GetDaysLikeMe(calendario.Value.Date).Take(50).Where(d => d.Date.Day > 28 && d.Date.Day < 2).Take(4);
}
else
{
    days = GetDaysLikeMe(calendario.Value.Date).Take(50).Where(d => d.Date.Day < 28 && d.Date.Day > 2).Take(4);
}
```

Comment: Might want to make that `IEnumerable<DateTime> days`

Comment: Ye that worked with Cory correction and your answer!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable outside the if block (without assigning a value - you can't use `var` in this case though, you'll have to specify the type), and then only assign a value to it inside.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code as it is now - you can easily define varables with `var` or explicitly specifying type inside any block, including `if`.

What likely happens is that you are trying to use this varable outside the block it is defined (i.e. after `if` statement) which is where `days` becomes undefined.

Fix: define variable outside the if, but you need explicit type there. If you have ReSharper it allows easily change between `var`/explicit type. Otherwise you'll have to figure out type yourself (in your case it is liklye `IEnumerable<DateTime>`).